# WCF and Stored Procedure Options

Tags: asp.net, t-sql, stored-procedures, wcf

I'm making my first WCF Service and I am unsure which route I should take with stored procedures and Linq to Sql. I understand that I can drag and drop stored procs to my DBML file and call them that way, or call them directly, not using the dbml. Is there a reason why i should choose one over the other? I guess I'm a little confused... Any input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, do you already have a Linq-to-SQL data model, which you use in your WCF service? If so, I would probably put my stored procedures into that data model.

If you don't already have and use a Linq-to-SQL data model, I don't really see much use and sense in creating one just to be able to call a stored procedure.

If you don't already have a Linq-to-SQL data model, I'd probably just use the straight ADO.NET code to call that stored procedure, send in any parameters coming from the WCF service method, and passing back any data you need to send back. In that case, you'd use a `SqlConnection`, a `SqlCommand` (`CommandType` set to `StoredProcedure`), a bunch of `SqlParameters`, and then call the `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` or `command.ExecuteReader()` methods (depending on what your stored proc is doing).

Comment: I do use a Linq to SQL data model already. I just didn't know if there was any added performance/functionality/standard if I use the Linq to SQL data model.

Comment: @Jisaak: no, not really - it's just easier to call the stored proc from your Linq-to-SQL data context since you don't need to deal with setting up connections and connection strings and so forth. Convenience: ++, performance: no benefit

Comment: Ok. Thats all I needed to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you come across a situation in which you may need to manipulate the arguments of the stored procedure dynamically, you may want to create a class that calls the stored procedure via WCF Service. Check how is done in this post.
[Executing SPs from WCF Service](http://willmtz.blogspot.com/2011/10/executing-stored-procedure-from-wcf.html)

Comment: Providing example code here, along with the link,  would ensure usefulness to future users. ;)